# Finding Process Info Associated to a Given Port in HP-UX

Tags: networking, process, open-files, hp-ux

I need to find information for a process that's using a given port number, such as   8080. More specifically, I'm interested in finding out the full path of the program.

How can I do that in HP-UX?

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps:

1. Find the PID (process ID) of the process using the port (e.g. 8080):

   ```
   lsof -i tcp:8080
   ```

   This will return: something like this:

   ```
   java       1829      154  101u  IPv4  0xd6cc04c0       0t0      TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
   ```

   The second column contains the PID we're after.
2. Find info about the process with a given PID (e.g 1829):

   ```
   ps -f -p 1829
   ```

   This will show, among other things, the path to the program of the process we're after:

   ```
   usr1  1829 20693  0 11:13:13 ?         1:37 /d03/app/jvm/hp142/jre/bin/PA_RISC2.0/java -ms512M
   ```

Comment: You can get LSOF for hpux from here: https://h20392.www2.hp.com/portal/swdepot/displayProductInfo.do?productNumber=HPUXIEXP1131 or http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/hpux/Sysadmin/lsof-4.89/

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
netstat -nlp | grep tcp | grep <PORT>
```

It should list the process in the last column, however if it does not, try to prepend sudo to that command or run that command as root.

**EDIT:** This appears not to work on hpux, but It should work on linux, and will be useful for future people, so I won't delete it.

Comment: Doesn't work on HPUX: # netstat -nlp
netstat: illegal option -- l

Comment: Try `netstat -np` note the missing l

Comment: still no good. -n works